# Objective-C crash with zombie object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, gcdasyncsocket

I've made an implementation for an JSON-RPC (a little bit modified) Server/Client in objective-c with the GCDAsyncSocket library. but the app crashes on responding to an request. without debugging for zombies i'm getting this error:

```
JSONRPCTestServer(1301,0x7fff7f887960) malloc: *** error for object 0x10014db10: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

the screenshot in xcode shows the error is in the completeCurrentRead method of the GCDAsyncSocket library.
[image]

when debugging for zombies it logs this:

2013-02-04 14:36:16.430 JSONRPCTestServer[1367:603] *** -[__NSArrayI release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1005b6fd0

and instruments shows this:
[image: instruments]

as this happens when a response to the rpc-call is of type nsarray i'd guess its this array that is causing the error. the rpc-method is:

```
-(NSArray *)testArray:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock {
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"test1",@"test2", nil];
}
```

The JSON-RPC header is:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "JSONRPCMethod.h"
#import "JSONRPCResponse.h"
#import "JSONRPCError.h"
#import "JSONRPCArgument.h"
#import "JSONRPCRequest.h"
#import "GCDAsyncSocket.h"

@class GCDAsyncSocket;

@protocol JSONRPCResponseDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
-(void)rpcSocket:(GCDAsyncSocket*)sock returnedValue:(id)retVal forMethod:(NSString*)m id:(id)i;
-(void)rpcSocket:(GCDAsyncSocket*)sock returnedError:(JSONRPCError*)err forMethod:(NSString*)m id:(id)i;
-(void)rpcReturnedValue:(id)retVal forMethod:(NSString*)m id:(id)i;
-(void)rpcReturnedError:(JSONRPCError*)err forMethod:(NSString*)m id:(id)i;
@end

@interface JSONRPC : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *supportedMethods;

    GCDAsyncSocket *mainSocket;
    NSMutableArray *connectedSockets;

    NSMutableArray *responseDelegates;
    BOOL isServer;
}

+(JSONRPC*)sharedConnection;

-(BOOL)startServer:(NSUInteger)port;
-(BOOL)connectToServer:(NSString*)host port:(NSUInteger)port;

-(BOOL)addMethod:(JSONRPCMethod*)method;
-(void)removeMethod:(JSONRPCMethod*)method;
-(void)removeMethodsWithTarget:(id)target;

-(void)sendRequest:(JSONRPCRequest*)req toSocket:(GCDAsyncSocket*)sock;
-(void)sendRequest:(JSONRPCRequest*)req;

-(void)sendNotification:(JSONRPCRequest*)req toSocket:(GCDAsyncSocket*)sock;
-(void)sendNotification:(JSONRPCRequest*)req;
-(void)sendNotification:(JSONRPCRequest*)req toSocketsWithUserData:(id)userData;


@end
```

.m is:

```
#import "JSONRPC.h"
#import "GCDAsyncSocket.h"

#define kGeneralReadTimeout -1.0
#define kGeneralWriteTimeout -1.0

@implementation JSONRPC

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        isServer = NO;
        supportedMethods = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        mainSocket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
        connectedSockets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        responseDelegates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

+ (JSONRPC *)sharedConnection {
    static JSONRPC *sharedSingleton;

    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if (!sharedSingleton)
            sharedSingleton = [[JSONRPC alloc] init];

        return sharedSingleton;
    }
}

-(BOOL)startServer:(NSUInteger)port {
    // Now we tell the socket to accept incoming connections.
    // We don't care what port it listens on, so we pass zero for the port number.
    // This allows the operating system to automatically assign us an available port.
    isServer = YES;
    NSError *err = nil;
    if ([mainSocket acceptOnPort:port error:&err]) {

    } else {
        DDLogError(@"Error while starting JSON-RPC Server: %@",err);
        return NO;
    }

    DDLogInfo(@"Started JSON-RPC Server on port %hu",[mainSocket localPort]);
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)connectToServer:(NSString *)host port:(NSUInteger)port {
    NSError *err = nil;
    mainSocket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [mainSocket connectToHost:host onPort:port error:&err];
    if(err != nil) {
        DDLogError(@"Couldn't connect to host %@:%lu (Error: %@)",host,port,err);
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)addMethod:(JSONRPCMethod *)method {
    for (JSONRPCMethod *meth in supportedMethods) {
        if([meth.name isEqualToString:method.name]) {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    [supportedMethods addObject:method];
    return YES;
}

-(void)removeMethod:(JSONRPCMethod *)method {
    [supportedMethods removeObject:method];
}

-(void)removeMethodsWithTarget:(id)target {
    NSMutableArray *toRemove = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (JSONRPCMethod *meth in supportedMethods) {
        if(meth.target == target) {
            [toRemove addObject:meth];
        }
    }
    [supportedMethods removeObjectsInArray:toRemove];
}

-(void)sendRequest:(JSONRPCRequest *)req toSocket:(GCDAsyncSocket*)sock {
    [responseDelegates addObject:req];
    [req setIdentifier:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:[responseDelegates count]-1]];
    [self sendPackage:[req dictionary] toSocket:sock];
}

-(void)sendRequest:(JSONRPCRequest *)req {
    [self sendRequest:req toSocket:mainSocket];
}

-(void)sendNotification:(JSONRPCRequest *)req toSocket:(GCDAsyncSocket*)sock{
    [req setIdentifier:nil];
    [self sendPackage:[req dictionary] toSocket:sock];
}

-(void)sendNotification:(JSONRPCRequest *)req {
    [self sendNotification:req toSocket:mainSocket];
}

-(void)sendNotification:(JSONRPCRequest *)req toSocketsWithUserData:(id)userData {
    NSMutableArray *matchingSockets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (GCDAsyncSocket*sock in connectedSockets) {
        if(sock.userData == userData) {
            [matchingSockets addObject:sock];
        }
    }
    if(matchingSockets.count == 0)
        return;

    [req setIdentifier:nil];
    NSData *pkgData = [self writableDataFromDictionary:[req dictionary]];
    for (GCDAsyncSocket*sock in matchingSockets) {
        [sock writeData:pkgData withTimeout:kGeneralWriteTimeout tag:0];
    }
}


#pragma mark Socket Delegate

- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didAcceptNewSocket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)newSocket {
    [connectedSockets addObject:newSocket];
    [newSocket readDataToData:[GCDAsyncSocket ZeroData] withTimeout:kGeneralReadTimeout tag:0];
}

- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didConnectToHost:(NSString *)host port:(UInt16)port {
    DDLogVerbose(@"socket:didConnectToHost:%@ port:%hu", host, port);
    [sock readDataToData:[GCDAsyncSocket ZeroData] withTimeout:kGeneralReadTimeout tag:0];
}

- (void)socketDidDisconnect:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock withError:(NSError *)err {
    DDLogVerbose(@"socketDidDisconnect:%@", err);
    if(isServer)
        [connectedSockets removeObject:sock];
}


-(void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag {
    // So, we've received something from the client
    // As we have to cut out the last 0x00 for JSONSerialization it has to be longer than 1 byte
    if(data.length > 1) {
        // Shorten out that 0x00
        data = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, data.length-1)];
        // Try to serialize
        NSError *err;
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&err];
        DDLogVerbose(@"Dict: %@",dict);
        if(err != nil) {
            // The package isn't json
            JSONRPCResponse *response = [JSONRPCResponse responseWithError:[JSONRPCError invalidRequest]];
            [self sendPackage:[response dictionary] toSocket:sock];
        } else {
            JSONRPCResponse *response = [self handleDictionary:dict fromSocket:sock];
            if(response != nil) {
                [self sendPackage:[response dictionary] toSocket:sock];
            }
        }
    }
    [sock readDataToData:[GCDAsyncSocket ZeroData] withTimeout:kGeneralReadTimeout tag:0];
}

-(JSONRPCResponse*)handleDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dict fromSocket:(GCDAsyncSocket*)sock {
    // Check if the "id" is of a correct value/type
    id identifier = [dict valueForKey:@"id"];
    if(!(identifier == nil || [identifier isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])) {
        return [JSONRPCResponse responseWithError:[JSONRPCError invalidRequest]];
    }

    // Handle the package
    NSString *methodName = [dict valueForKey:@"method"];
    id errorValue = [dict valueForKey:@"error"];
    id resultValue = [dict valueForKey:@"result"];
    if([methodName isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        // We have a string as method
        DDLogInfo(@"Method: %@, object: %@",methodName,[dict valueForKey:@"params"]);
        for (JSONRPCMethod *method in supportedMethods) {
            if([method.name isEqualToString:methodName]) {
                id result = nil;
                if(isServer == YES) {
                    // It is a server and the method needs to know from where the call comes
                    result = [method invoke:[dict valueForKey:@"params"] fromSocket:sock];
                } else {
                    // It is a client and we don't need to know where the call is from. it can only be the server.
                    result = [method invoke:[dict valueForKey:@"params"]];
                }
                if([result isKindOfClass:[JSONRPCError class]]) {
                    return [JSONRPCResponse responseWithError:result id:identifier];
                } else if(result != nil) {
                    return [JSONRPCResponse responseWithResult:result id:identifier];
                } else {
                    return nil;
                }
            }
        }
    } else if(resultValue != nil) {
        // We have a response from our partner
        //DDLogInfo(@"Result: %@",resultValue);
        NSUInteger responseDelegateId = [identifier unsignedIntegerValue];
        if(responseDelegateId < [responseDelegates count]) {
            JSONRPCRequest *originalRequest = [responseDelegates objectAtIndex:responseDelegateId];
            if(originalRequest.sender == nil) {
                return nil;
            }
            @try {
                SEL selector;
                if(isServer) {
                    selector = @selector(rpcSocket:returnedValue:forMethod:id:);
                } else {
                    selector = @selector(rpcReturnedValue:forMethod:id:);
                }
                NSMethodSignature *signature = [originalRequest.sender methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
                NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
                [invocation setTarget:originalRequest.sender];
                [invocation setSelector:selector];
                NSUInteger startArg = 2;
                if(isServer) {
                    [invocation setArgument:&sock atIndex:startArg];
                    startArg++;
                }
                NSString *method = [originalRequest method];
                id orgId = [originalRequest identifier];
                [invocation setArgument:&resultValue atIndex:startArg];
                [invocation setArgument:&method atIndex:startArg+1];
                [invocation setArgument:&orgId atIndex:startArg+2];
                [invocation invoke];
            }
            @catch (NSException *exception) {
                DDLogWarn(@"Couldn't find a response: %@",exception);
            }
        }
    } else if(errorValue != nil) {
        // We have a string as method
        DDLogInfo(@"Error: %@",errorValue);
    } else {
        return [JSONRPCResponse responseWithError:[JSONRPCError invalidRequest] id:identifier];
    }
    return nil;
}

-(void)sendPackage:(NSDictionary *)dict toSocket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock {
    NSData *answerData = [self writableDataFromDictionary:dict];
    [sock writeData:answerData withTimeout:kGeneralWriteTimeout tag:0];
}

-(NSData*)writableDataFromDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dict {
    NSMutableData *answerData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    // Serialize the answer
    NSError *err = nil;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:&err];
    if(err != nil) {
        // Log
        DDLogError(@"JSON-RPC had an internal error while converting the answer to JSON. The answer-dictionary is: %@",dict);
        // Form answer manually
        jsonData = [NSData dataWithBytes:"{\"error\":{\"code\":-32700,\"message\":\"Parse error\"}}"
                                  length:49];
    }
    // Format the answer
    [answerData appendData:jsonData];
    [answerData appendData:[GCDAsyncSocket ZeroData]];
    return answerData;
}
```

i just don't know how to fix this. why do i keep getting an error with an nsarray but when i return a nsnumber it works? how can i fix this?

Comment: NSNumbers with integer values in at least some range get interned and reused, and some NSNumbers on some architectures may not even be allocated objects at all, but rather tagged pointers. Either way, you won't see over-release crashes with those kinds of objects. Same with NSString literals (not sure about other objects created from literals).

Comment: thanks, but how can i get nsarrays to work?

Comment: Find out which array is the one getting prematurely released (guessing does not count), and find out what's either releasing it when it shouldn't or not retaining it when it should. Use Instruments's Zombies template to see where the array was created and its entire history, and then look at the stack trace of each retain, autorelease, and release in that history to find the one that is missing or doesn't fit.

Comment: i've updated the question with an image from instruments. it's the object allocated in the response for the rpc-call. but i don't know why it's so often released in _dispatch_call_block_and_release..

Comment: Yup, that's what you need to be looking at. Look at each event's stack trace and try to pair up retains with autoreleases/releases.

Comment: yeah, but i don't get why _dispatch_call_block_and_release calls release 3 times?